# In fullcalendar2.9.0 , How to show a "CHECK-MARK (icon )" in the event date day cell. where color of the check-mark depends on some threshold value

Tags: fullcalendar

```
viewRender: function (view) {
     $("div.fc-content").prepend("(+) ");
}
```

In the above code i have added '+' mark instead of icon just to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

To add some text, add a span with a class that will depend on your threshold value. In this example I am adding a (+) mark to all events. I assume this is what you meant.

```
$(".fc-content-skeleton .fc-time")
    .prepend("<span class='your-color-style'>(+)</span>");
```